# X is not defined but x has been defined

Tags: python, variables, calculator, micropython

I am writing a program for the ti-84 using python. It is designed to get a differential equation from the user, process it, and draw a slope point field for that equation.
The part that is giving me issues is the eval function (I know, security risk) when i evaluate the equation it gives me an error, 'name 'x' is not defined'.
This error only occurs when running the program on the calculator, it does not occur when I run that section of code on my computer. The problem is that 'x' has already been defined above. Why is this happening?

```
import ti_pltlib as plt
class Field:

   self.equation = 2*x+2*y

   for pos_x in range(plt.xmin, plt.xmax):
       for pos_y in range(plt.ymin, plt.ymax):
           x = pos_x-0.25
           y = pos_y-0.25
           x0 = eval(self.equation) #Error occurs right here
           x += 0.5
           x1 = eval(self.equation)
           y0 = eval(self.equation)
           y += 0.5
           y1 = eval(self.equation)
```

The error in more detail is:

```
 'File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "FEILD.py", line 45, in <module>
 File "FEILD.py", line 45, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'x' is not defined'
```

Comment: What is `self` and specifically `self.equation` here? Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Beyond the obvious that using `eval` is always a bad idea I can't help but wonder what you think `x1 = eval(self.equation)` followed by `y0 = eval(self.equation)` is going to do. I would expect the same result to be assigned to both `x1` and `y0`. So why evaluate the expression twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the TI-84 runs micropython (well, circuitpython), and **MicroPython is not Python**. You need to be aware of the differences when writing code in both languages. In this case, you are hitting the fact that [`eval()` in micropython does not have access to local variables](https://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.9.3/pyboard/genrst/core_language.html#code-running-in-eval-function-doesn-t-have-access-to-local-variables):

> MicroPython doesn’t maintain symbolic local environment, it is optimized to an array of slots. Thus, local variables can’t be accessed by a name. Effectively, eval(expr) in MicroPython is equivalent to eval(expr, globals(), globals()).

That [entire document](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/genrst/core_language.html) is good reading; it talks about a number of differences between CPython (aka "regular Python") and MicroPython.

Comment: Would exec() be a good workaround for this issue? Or could I just use the eval(expr, globals(), globals())?

Comment: You wouldn't use `eval(expr, globals(), globals())` because that would be invalid syntax. The docs are telling you that `eval(expr)` in micropython is equivalent to `eval(expr, globals(), globals())` in regular python. I don't think there's a sane way to do this in micropython; for `eval` to work the way you want you would need to put all your values in global variables.

Comment: @FinnPearson `exec` and `eval` are not equivalent. See https://medium.com/@techclaw/python-eval-vs-exec-understanding-the-key-differences-f88d6ab85c0d (among many other docs if you google "python exec vs eval"). As you seem to understand but it's worth reinforcing: Using either `exec` or `eval` is risky and should be avoided unless you have complete control of the string passed to either function.